# Passing data from a react component to python-flask api

Tags: python, reactjs, flask

Is there any typical approach for passing the data from a react component to a python-flask api for processing that data? Or any resources/examples where I can learn to integrate/include python-flask with react ?

Comment: Use Axios library to make a POST or GET API call

Comment: Hey Ashish, thanks for your answer. I had an idea in mind about using axios in this situation. But had few doubts which are as follow:
1) Will i need to run my python flask application independently w.r.t the react ones, so that all the api's exposed from my python application can serve requests from react?
2) If not what would you suggest for a better approach? 

Thank you!

Comment: Yes.. you need to run flask api at a port so that you can make requests from the axios

Comment: Oh ok. I will surely try this out. Thanks for the help.Cheers!